# How to install tar binary in my Kubernetes container for kubectl cp to work?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, file-copying

My kubectl cp isnt working due to tar not being in my bin folder of my container. I can't seem to find how to get it installed.

I get an error when trying:

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir
```

**Error:**

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:
> container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec:
> "tar": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: it does indeed looks like your container doesn't have tar installed. In order to know how to install it, one would need to also know what is the image of that container, did you build it, is it a public image, if so, which one?

Comment: Usually tar(1) will be part of the core OS -- there's even an implementation of it in BusyBox -- so if you don't have it, you're likely running some sort of "scratch" or "distroless" image and it won't be possible to install additional software, and `kubectl cp` won't work with this image.

Comment: @iAmHereForHelp Your container does not have tar installed(it should be included by default). Try to reinstall your previous chosen OS or try a different Linux distros.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is no Tar into your Docker

I would suggest installing the Tar first at the above **Dockerfile** level commands

You can add the Tar into Docker using

**Docker image** : `RUN yum install -y tar`

Comment: I got this error: `/bin/sh: 1: yum: not found`

Comment: yum command is not exist in your base image, you can use an alternative like apt-get, pacman or apk as per the base image and install the Tar.